# C++ std::array wrapper

Tags: c++, c++17

I implemented a `std::array` wrapper which primarily adds various constructors, since [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) has no explicit constructors itself, but rather uses aggregate initialization.

I like to have some feedback on my code which heavily depends on template meta-programming. More particularly:

- Are there still cases where I can exploit move semantics or where I will unnecessarily copy large values (which can become a problem for large array elements)?
- Are there still cases where I can use more stringent conditions for enabling methods (i.e. SFINAE)? (e.g. type deduction/decaying of tuple elements).
- Are there elegant strategies for supporting `Array`s containing only one element (or even no elements at all)? (Note the potential conflicts with the copy and move constructor. `Array` needs to be capable of handling pointer elements as well in the presence of inheritance. Furthermore, `Array` will act as a base class in my code base.)?
- Is it possible to chain `Array` constructors instead of always immediately redirect to `std::array` itself?
- General guidelines, best practices?

[Try It Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AafJOz63vJw7gWfz)

**Includes**:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
```

**Array Utilities**:

```
namespace details {

    template< typename ActionT, typename FromT, size_t...I >
    constexpr decltype(auto) TransformArray(ActionT action, 
                                            const std::array< FromT, sizeof...(I) >& a,
                                            std::index_sequence< I... >) {

        using ToT = decltype(std::declval< ActionT >()(std::declval< FromT >()));
        return std::array< ToT, sizeof...(I) >{ action(a[I])... };
    }

    template< typename T, size_t...I >
    constexpr decltype(auto) FillArray(T value, std::index_sequence< I... >) {
        return std::array< T, sizeof...(I) >{ (static_cast< void >(I), value)... };
    }

    template< size_t ToN, typename T, size_t...I >
    constexpr decltype(auto) EnlargeArray(const std::array< T, sizeof...(I) >& a,
                                          std::index_sequence< I... >) {

        return std::array< T, ToN >{ a[I]... };
    }

    template< typename T, typename TupleT, std::size_t... I >
    constexpr decltype(auto) TuppleToArray(const TupleT& t, 
                                           std::index_sequence< I... >) {

        return std::array< T, sizeof...(I) >{ std::get< I >(t)... };
    }
}

template< typename ActionT, typename FromT, size_t N >
constexpr decltype(auto) TransformArray(ActionT action,
                                        const std::array< FromT, N >& a) {

    return details::TransformArray(std::move(action), a,
                                   std::make_index_sequence< N >());
}

template< typename ToT, typename FromT, size_t N >
constexpr decltype(auto) StaticCastArray(const std::array< FromT, N >& a) {
    constexpr auto f = [](const FromT& v) {
        return static_cast< ToT >(v); 
    };
    return TransformArray(f, a);
}

template< typename ToT, typename FromT, size_t N >
constexpr decltype(auto) DynamicCastArray(const std::array< FromT, N >& a) {
    constexpr auto f = [](const FromT& v) {
        return dynamic_cast< ToT >(v); 
    };
    return TransformArray(f, a);
}

template< typename ToT, typename FromT, size_t N >
constexpr decltype(auto) ConstCastArray(const std::array< FromT, N >& a) {
    constexpr auto f = [](const FromT& v) {
        return const_cast< ToT >(v); 
    };
    return TransformArray(f, a);
}

template< typename ToT, typename FromT, size_t N >
constexpr decltype(auto) ReinterpretCastArray(const std::array< FromT, N >& a) {
    constexpr auto f = [](const FromT& v) {
        return reinterpret_cast< ToT >(v); 
    };
    return TransformArray(f, a);
}

template< typename T, size_t N >
constexpr decltype(auto) FillArray(T value) {
    return details::FillArray(value, std::make_index_sequence< N >());
}

template< size_t ToN, typename T, size_t FromN >
constexpr decltype(auto) EnlargeArray(const std::array< T, FromN >& a) {
    return details::EnlargeArray< ToN >(a, std::make_index_sequence< FromN >());
}

template< typename T, typename... Ts >
constexpr decltype(auto) TuppleToArray(const std::tuple< T, Ts... >& t) {
    constexpr auto N = sizeof...(Ts) + 1u;
    return details::TuppleToArray< T >(t, std::make_index_sequence< N >());
}
```

**Tuple Utilities**:

```
namespace details {

    template< typename T, size_t...I >
    constexpr decltype(auto) ArrayToTupple(const std::array< T, sizeof...(I) >& a, 
                                           std::index_sequence< I... >) noexcept {
        return std::make_tuple(a[I]...);
    }
}

template< typename T, size_t N >
constexpr decltype(auto) ArrayToTupple(const std::array< T, N >& a) noexcept {
    return details::ArrayToTupple(a, std::make_index_sequence< N >());
}

template< typename... ArgsT >
constexpr decltype(auto) ArgsToTuple(ArgsT&&... args) noexcept {
    return std::make_tuple(std::forward< ArgsT >(args)...);
}
```

**Array wrapper**:

```
template< typename T, size_t N, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t< (N > 1) > >  
struct Array : std::array< T, N > {

    constexpr Array() noexcept
        : std::array< T, N >{} {}

    template< typename... ArgsT, 
              typename = std::enable_if_t< (N == sizeof...(ArgsT)) > >
    constexpr Array(ArgsT&&... args) noexcept
        : std::array< T, N >{ std::forward< ArgsT >(args)... } {}

    template< size_t FromN, 
              typename = std::enable_if_t< (FromN < N) > >
    constexpr Array(const Array< T, FromN >& a) noexcept
        : std::array< T, N >(EnlargeArray< N >(a)) {}

    template< size_t FromN, typename... ArgsT, 
              typename = std::enable_if_t< (FromN < N && (FromN + sizeof...(ArgsT)) == N) > >
    constexpr Array(const Array< T, FromN >& a, ArgsT&&... args) noexcept
        : std::array< T, N >(TuppleToArray(
            std::tuple_cat(ArrayToTupple(a), ArgsToTuple(std::forward< ArgsT >(args)...)))) {}

    constexpr Array(const Array& a) noexcept = default;

    constexpr Array(Array&& a) noexcept = default;

    template< typename U >
    constexpr explicit Array(const Array< U, N >& a) noexcept
        : std::array< T, N >(StaticCastArray< T >(a)) {}

    ~Array() = default;

    constexpr Array& operator=(const Array& a) noexcept = default;

    constexpr Array& operator=(Array&& a) noexcept = default;

    // It would be nice to have properties in C++ (supported in msvc++ and Clang).

    constexpr std::enable_if_t< ( 1 <= N ), T& > GetX() noexcept {
        return std::array< T, N >::operator[](0);
    }
    constexpr std::enable_if_t< ( 2 <= N ), T& > GetY() noexcept {
        return std::array< T, N >::operator[](1);
    }
    constexpr std::enable_if_t< ( 3 <= N ), T& > GetZ() noexcept {
        return std::array< T, N >::operator[](2);
    }
    constexpr std::enable_if_t< ( 4 <= N ), T& > GetW() noexcept {
        return std::array< T, N >::operator[](3);
    }

    constexpr std::enable_if_t< ( 1 <= N ), const T& > GetX() const noexcept {
        return std::array< T, N >::operator[](0);
    }
    constexpr std::enable_if_t< ( 2 <= N ), const T& > GetY() const noexcept {
        return std::array< T, N >::operator[](1);
    }
    constexpr std::enable_if_t< ( 3 <= N ), const T& > GetZ() const noexcept {
        return std::array< T, N >::operator[](2);
    }
    constexpr std::enable_if_t< ( 4 <= N ), const T& > GetW() const noexcept {
        return std::array< T, N >::operator[](3);
    }
};
```

**Some extra utilities for illustration purposes**:

```
template< typename T, std::size_t N >
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::array< T, N >& a) {
    for (auto i : a) { os << i << ' '; }
    return os << '\n';
}

int main() {
    constexpr Array< float, 5 > a;
    std::cout << a;

    constexpr Array< float, 5 > b( 1.5f, 2.5f, 3.5f, 4.5f, 5.5f );
    std::cout << b;

    constexpr Array< float, 5 > c{ 1.5f, 2.5f, 3.5f, 4.5f, 5.5f };
    std::cout << c;

    constexpr Array< float, 6 > d(c);
    std::cout << d;

    constexpr Array< float, 6 > e(c, 6.5f);
    std::cout << e;

    constexpr Array< int, 6 > f(e);
    std::cout << f;

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit 1**:
[Try It Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U3L86n3NzgdII5pm)

- `auto` instead of `decltype(auto)` (*all methods return by value*) **(thanks to Incomputable)**
- Universal reference for `ActionT` + perfect forwarding of `ActionT` **(thanks to Incomputable)**

**Edit 2**:
[Try It Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ll6cxowhQCfKMHTe)

- All accessor/getter member methods are removed from `Array`, since they are not applicable to all possible derived classes of `Array`. A RGB color spectrum does not have X,Y,Z components, whereas a XYZ color spectrum does. A UVW normalized 3D texture position has its W component at index 2, whereas a 4D homogeneous position has its W component at index 3. Derived classes can implement these accessor/getter member methods themselves or inherit from pure abstract classes (as mentioned and illustrated by Incomputable). Furthermore, it is possible to add a `size_t Index` template argument to specify the right index. Depending on the size of T, one can also return by value for small values, and by const reference for large values. Depending on the type of T, one can use different call conventions as well (e.g. `__vectorcall`, `__fastcall`, etc.).
- `ArgsToTupple` is removed, since it is just a wrapper around `std::make_tupple`.
- An extra alignment template argument `A` is added to `Array`. Furthermore, some extra `explicit` constructors are added to support converting between `Array` instances with a different alignment.

**Edit 3**:
[Try It Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AxNaZAq5fg5HBIjH)

- Added a constructor for replicating a single value. This makes sense in the absence of `Array`s of at most one element. I personally see no use case for a `std::array< T, 0 >` or `std::array< T, 1 >` either, given that the number of elements needs to be known at compile time.
- Added a `std::is_convertible_v` type trait to construct an `Array` from a given `Array` containing elements of a different type. This enables the construction of an `Array< Array< T, N1 >, N2 >` by replicating a single `Array< T, N1 >` using the newly added constructor.

Comment: Great. Now make a github repo and share it with the world.

Comment: @Pheo: [Github: just the sample](https://github.com/matt77hias/cpp-samples/blob/master/Samples/array/code.hpp) | [Github: larger project using the sample](https://github.com/matt77hias/MAGE) ;)

Comment: Um... Dang. That's a big project.

Comment: @Matthias, I recommend waiting a little bit before accepting an answer. People feel discouraged to post their own if one is already accepted. One or two days is usually a good time period.

Comment: @Incomputable Ok, I will postpone accepting an answer.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Feel free to post a follow-up question instead :-)

Comment: @Mast My apologies, but the `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `dynamic_cast` is mostly boilerplate code which is not used anywhere else. Furthermore, I also realized that `reinterpret_cast` and `dynamic_cast` could not occur in non-templated `constexpr` functions. Since I use template functions, this is kind of hidden (i.e. the template instantiations will never be `constexpr`).

Comment: And there's no problem whatsoever explaining that in a follow-up question. Might want to link back to this one for bonus context and comparison :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Encouraging ineffective/wrong usage

May be for your usage case it is important, but casts are usually an indication that something could be improved or fixed. `static_cast`s are usually implicit. `dynamic_cast`s are somewhat arguable, but there should be some better solution, albeit harder to find. `const_cast`s are outright wrong (there is a case when non-const member function calls const version and then `const_cast`s the constness away). `reinterpret_cast`s are usually done in a more explicit manner. Having them hidden somewhere is asking for trouble.

### decltype(auto)

I argued with @Quuxplusone about the feature. I argued that it is safe to use in general. I was wrong. The feature requires a great deal of care to be used correctly. This case is borderline dangerous. *Never* use `decltype(auto)` where value needs to be returned. Don't use it unless reference is expected and the referenceness needs to be preserved.

### Accept by forwarding reference

Some people also call it generalized reference. It is particularly applicable to `ActionT`. IIRC the new wording says that the temporaries do not need to fully "materialize" if they will not outlive the scope. Transform function could take input array by forwarding reference too, as not all actions might operate on const array elements.

### Inheriting constructors

It would be better to use "using declarations" (thanks to @BenSteffan) to inherit constructors and duplicate them as part of `Array`.

### Curiously recurring templates

In my opinion, rather than adding every possible utility member function, one should write `x_getter<T>`, which SFINAE's correctly based on `T`. That will reduce the interface bloat greatly and allows people to choose.

Here is an example of `x_getter` I mentioned in the comments on a stub class:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct x_getter
{
    friend T;

    double x() const
    {
        return (*static_cast<const T*>(this))[0];
    }

    void x(double new_x)
    {
        (*static_cast<T*>(this))[0] = new_x;
    }

private:
    x_getter() = default; //prevents accidental creation
};

struct coordinates : std::array<double, 3>, x_getter<coordinates>
{
    using std::array<double, 3>::array;
};


int main()
{
    coordinates origin{};
    std::cout << origin.x();
    origin.x(12.7);
    std::cout << ' ' << origin.x() << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kSoNYzYW3sftNOB9).

It actually took me a trip to stackoverflow to get it to work, but now I understand why it works. `static_cast`  is the right cast, because it will cast downwards the inheritance tree, and the only child that can hold the getter is `T` itself, thus no `dynamic_cast` is needed. It would be great though to smoothen out the ugly casts. I believe it also has a disadvantage in aggregates, but I believe it is not applicable in this case.

Now you can write several of these facades, and let users choose which ones they want. This will make mixing and matching easier for users. Also, `[[no_unique_address]]` in C++20 will make it as efficient as hand written code (currently they take up a little bit of space inside of the object, in C++20 empty base optimization will hopefully be performed using the tags).

### Naming convention

The convention is rather unusual, and more C# style. Also, names could follow more standard library style to be grasped immediately. For example, `TransformArray` could be renamed to `transform_construct`, and be placed into `utils` namespace.

### Tuple utilities

`std::array` is considered to be tuple by standard library. All of the helpers for `std::tuple` work the same way for `std::array` in terms of template metaprogramming. Thus the utilities are not too useful.

Comment: "expression (statement?)" -> Actually neither, this is a using-_declaration_ (please excuse the pedantic nit-picking).

Comment: @BenSteffan, thanks, and you're welcome to nit-pick.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed feedback! 1) Currently, I do not have a practical use case for all my cast functions except for the static_cast (which I prefer to have explicitly combined with the maximal warning level for compiling). The idea of having each cast is based on the std's methods for std::shared_ptr (e.g. std::static_pointer_cast, etc.). Though, I definitely agree that this kind of hides the casts. 2) So auto will do in all my cases? I thought the decltype type deduction wouldn't hurt (whereas auto's template type deduction could be overlooked in some cases where it would have mattered.

Comment: @Matthias, as I mentioned, when you want to return a *value*, don't use `decltype(auto)`. `auto` will do quite well. `decltype(auto)` is useful in cases where you want to preserve referenceness, otherwise I would stay away from it, to not return a reference to temporary accidentally (compiler will probably emit a warning, but still it shouldn't be allowed).

Comment: 4) I do not really understand why I would need the using declaration in Array (neither do I hide std::array< T, N >::operator[](size_t), neither do I use private inheritance)? But this is much cleaner than all the std::array< T, N >::operator[](size_t) operator calls. 5) What do you mean with x_getter<T>? 6) My naming convention resembles Windows and other Microsoft APIs (I use the std syntax for (member) variables only). 7) ArrayToTupple is redundant, you mean?

Comment: @Matthias, 4) I just thought that you got tired of duplicating all of the member functions. 5) I'll update the post with example, but it will take time 6) That is why I usually place naming conventions downwards, as long as they're consistently applied it is ok 7) I meant that `std::tuple_element`, `std::tuple_size` work the same way on tuples and arrays, and everything else is handled by your other functions.

Comment: @Matthias, I updated the post with example of CRTP.

Comment: @Matthias, you’re right about fourth point. Only constructor inheritance is useful. I’ll update the post tomorrow. I’m going to sleep, but I’ll answer your questions tomorrow, so you can pile them up :)

Answer (score 2):

Would it be better to have clearly labeled `make_array` functions for each kind of construction?

```
auto a1 = make_repeated<int,15>(42);
auto a2 = array_from_tuple (t);
```

Can we count on the compiler to elide the prvalue and construct the declared variable in-place without any copying?  If so, you can effectively write *named* constructors.

Comment: My actual use case is to let multiple classes inherit from `Array`. This is a possible alternative at the cost of always calling the right labeled functions in all child class constructors. These child class constructors, however, cannot be replaced (1) since I rely on explicit/implicit constructors depending on the conversions I want to support and (2) since I still want initializations via a constructor (e.g. RGB rgb(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);). Unfortunately, I use the base `Array` as well for which I still like the same kind of initializations via a constructor.

Comment: The labeled functions, however, are more expressive, since at the moment I am not able to integrate the replication of a single value (confusing in my current setup).

Comment: Replicate single value: **hint:**  `index_sequence`, comma operator, pack expansion in initializer list.

Comment: I already have that method (see array utilities above). It just seems  confusing to add it in a non-labeled constructor. But at a second thought, I can make it an explicit constructor.

Comment: In C++17, the return value optimization is *mandated* by the standard, so we can safely rely on it :)